# How to prove $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ form a fundamental set of solutions to Linear System $Y' = AY$ when eigenvalues of $A$ are defective

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Sorry for the long prose.

I am trying to understand a naive treatment of the solution to the Linear System with constant coefficients $$ \left({   \begin{matrix}
        y_1(t)  \\
        y_2(t)  \\
        y_3(t) \\
        \end{matrix}} \right) = A_{3 \times 3} \left({   \begin{matrix}
        y_1'(t)  \\
        y_2'(t)  \\
        y_3'(t) \\
        \end{matrix}} \right) $$

when the eigenvalues of $A$ may be defective.

**Case 1:** $A$ has only one eigenvalue $\lambda$ of multiplicity $ 3$ but with geometric multiplicity $1$ - that is space of corresponding eigenvectors of $\lambda$ is of dimension $1$. My notes tell me we need to look for solutions of the form $$Y_1 = X_1  e^{\lambda t}  $$ $$ Y_2  = [X_1  t + X_2] e^{\lambda t} $$ $$ Y_3 = [X_1  \dfrac{t^2}{2}  + X_2  t + X_3 ] e^{\lambda t}  $$

where the equations $ (A - \lambda I)X_3 = X_2, \;\; (A - \lambda I)X_2 = X_1, \;\; (A - \lambda I)X_1 = 0  $ hold for non-zero $3 \times 1$ constant vectors $X_i$. I understand how the solutions are justified. But,

> How to prove that $Y_1, Y_2, Y_3$ are linearly independent solutions?
>   Or is it easier to first prove $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are linearly independent?

My notes exclude this bit and I am having trouble proving these. (Haven't learnt canonical forms. Knowledge on Linear Algebra only extends to basic details on Eigenvalues i.e. how they represent Invariant Subspaces).

Then I need to extend this to the case when $A$ has two eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ with $\lambda_1$ having Geometric and Algebraic Multiplicity $1$ and $\lambda_2$ having algebraic multiplicity $2$ and Geometric multiplicity $1$ - (one missing solution).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_1\dots a_3$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^3 a_iX_i=0$.

Let $I$ be the largest index with $a_i\ne0$, i.e.
$$
I = \max\{i : a_i \ne 0\}.
$$
Applying $(A-\lambda I)^{i-1}$ tho the linear combination above yields
$$
\sum_{i=1}^I a_i(A-\lambda I)^{i-1}X_i = a_I X_1,
$$
implying $a_I=0$. A contradiction.